# Cosa significa "a effetto"?

Tags: meaning

Ho trovato la seguente sigla:

> Siti per creare meme con frasi su immagini e citazioni a effetto

Cosa significa "a effetto" in questo contesto?

Comment: Si può intendere come: "una frase (di solito breve) che suscita una reazione immediata". Scrivo una risposta invece di un commento perché non ho una reputazione abbastanza elevata per commentare.

Comment: Dov'è la sigla? Una sigla è un acronimo, un'abbreviazione di qualcosa di più lungo (il nome di un'associazione, per esempio).

Comment: @DaG Sono quasi certo che Jack intendesse uno "slogan" non una "sigla".

Answer (score 6):

***[Ad effetto](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/E/effetto.php)*** è un'espressione idiomatica che significa:

> - di effetto, a sensazione, capace di suscitare impressione: *scena ad effetto; un abito di sicuro effetto

(Hoepli)

Comment: Aggiungo che _ad effetto_ viene anche utilizzato in contesto sportivo (per esempio parlando di calcio) in espressioni come _tiro ad effetto_ , _pallone ad effetto_ per indicare che al pallone è stata impressa una traettoria particolare e difficile da prevedere.